# Tcl Expect: How can you expect 2 matches in 1 line

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

How can you expect 2 matches in 1 line

```
expect "New password*" | "Retype"
send "something\r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-re` flag to enable the regular expression support.

```
 expect -re "New password*|Retype" 
 send "something\r"
```

Comment: Need to remove `*` or replace to `.*`, becouse it's not -ex anymore, but -re

Comment: Thanks @komar. Do you know how I can store that in a variable just like below

set StandardPrompt {[#>$] }

Comment: @carlregencia thanks to @Dinesh :) `set new_pass_regex {New password|Retype}` and then `expect -re $new_pass_regex`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is to switch to using the other form of `expect`:

```
expect {
   "New password*" {}
   "Retype" {}
}
send "something\r
```

The `{}` can be full scripts if you need to respond differently according to what sort of things happen. The `exp_continue` command is useful if you want to respond to something and keep on waiting:

```
expect {
   "New password*" {
       send "$thepassword\r"
       exp_continue
   }
   "Retype" {
       send "$thepassword\r"
       exp_continue
   }
   "thepromptyouexpectafterwards" {}
}
send "something else\r
```

Comment: Is there any shorter method to do this?